# Android detects instanceof EditText and instanceof TextView as the same

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext, textview

I have dynamically created Layout. It has some edittexts, textview, spinners, etc.

After it, I have to get the info I introduce on those views.

So Im doing something like this

```
for(int i=0;i <= childs;i++){
        View v=parent.getChildAt(i);
             if (v instanceof TextView) {
                //do something
            }
            else if (v instanceof EditText) {
               //do OTHER thing
            }
```

The problem here is that Android detects `v` always as `TextView` when the `View` is either `TextView` or `Edittext` (I have no problem with spinners or button).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `EditText` extends `TextView`.

switch the order of checking:

```
if (v instanceof EditText) {
     //do something
} else if (v instanceof TextView) {
     //do OTHER thing
}
```

Comment: 27 sec too late :D You deserved it bro :D +1

Answer (score 3):

Switch the order of the `if` statements. Put the `if (v instanceof EditText)` on the top so it checks that one first. The reason for this is that `EditText` directly extends (it would be the same if it were indirect) `TextView` and thus when something is an `EditText`, it automatically is the `TextView` as well, and therefore `instanceof` returns true there as well.

Answer (score 3):

To check for a specific class, use

```
if (v.getClass().equals(TextView.class)) {
  /* ... */
} else if (v.getClass().equals(Spinner.class)) {
  /* ... */
}
```

As Vucko and Ognian stated, `EditText` extends `TextView`, that's why your `instanceof` doesn't behave as you expected.